# in laravel breeze ,could I generate email verification link to my email by my own?

Tags: php, laravel, email, url

in laravel breeze I found that when it generates email verification link , it uses temporarySignedRoute mathod which
append a signature to the url conisiting of the id and hashed email ,but also the signature formed by hash-hmac and encode.
all the previous algorithms gives the same output for the same input.Now suppose I have a fake email that has no inbox at all
and registerd it , also suppose I have access to the database so I could findout what is my email id,and have the app encryption key...
if I used all the previous hash and encode algorithms could I generate a verification link to a fake email ?[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUDb0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsPV6.png)

laravel breeze email verification

Comment: If you want to do email verification link you could try the ff: 1, create a column in your user as uuid, 2, create a route to accept the said column. 3 using the uuid param, find your user, do your conditions if the uuid is valid, if still within the time, etc.

Comment: I meant could I generate the link for a fake email if I knew the id and used the same hash algorithms ?

Comment: Dont need to make it complicated with hash and that. Create a uuid column (verification_uuid) in your user table and create a route/controller method that accepts the uuid. From there you can just check if the uuid matches . As for checking if the uuid is valid or not, there are different ways to do so